# How do I get a Smooth Slope?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I made a 3D Scan of a house and I am trying to remodel it as a low poly version.
At the moment I am struggling to get a smooth slop where the grass is. Is somebody able to help me?
Link to the blender file: http://www.mediafire.com/file/403j9dltnezfbbj/Haus_Blender_komplett_Save_145.blend/file

Thanks a lot!

[image: remodeled version with awful slope]
[image: 3D Scan]

Comment: You'll need more polygons. Why are you using a single N-Gon?

Comment: When I use more polygons it’s to edged I think. And Im not sure how I could do this with more polygons. Do you have and advice?

Comment: using a single huge n-gon will not make your model less edgy. Actually Blender is triangulating it for the shader. The triangulation is just optimized that the 'edgyness' is minimal.

Comment: For surfaces that are curved in all direction I would go for a Grid, the resolution depends on you project's needs. You have to write down more info to get a proper answer.

Comment: What Information do you need?